# What is the difference between these two different ways of creating an object literal

Tags: javascript

Am just learning javascript coming from c#.  I have seen two ways of creating an object.  What is the difference between the two?  They seem to do the same thing.

```
var myContact = {

    first: "greg",
    last: "gum",
    fullName: function()
    {
        return this.first + " " + this.last;
    }

}

alert(myContact.fullName());


var myContact2 = function () {

    this.first = "greg";
    this.last = "gum";
    this.fullName = function()
    {
        return this.first + " " + this.last;
    }
};

var aContact = new myContact2();

alert(aContact.fullName());
```

Comment: I updated the code in the question.

Comment: check out this book - http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter8.html

Comment: Some answers about constructor functions vs. object also on SO, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559207/difference-between-a-constructor-and-an-object) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328449/what-difference-is-there-in-javascript-between-a-constructor-function-and-funct). Welcome to JavaScript :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**JavaScript objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

> - Can be created via literals
> - Can be assigned to variables, array entries, and properties of other objects
> - Can be passed as arguments to functions
> - Can be returned as values from functions
> - Can possess properties that can be dynamically created and assigned

[**JavaScript functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

> - All of the above
> - Additionally, functions can be invoked

Since functions in JavaScript posses all of the capabilities objects posses and they are called *first class objects*.

**Additional information:**

There are **four** ways to invoke a function in JavaScript. The way you are using it here is **invocation by constructor**

When the function is called as a constructor via the `new` operator, its context is defined as the new object instance. This means that we can initialize values within the constructor function via the `this` parameter (in addition to attaching properties via the prototype).

```js
var obj = function() { this.whatever = "hello"; } // 'this' refers to `obj`
var instance = new obj();
alert(instance.whatever);                         // alerts 'hello'
```

If we choose to do so, instance members created inside the constructor will occlude properties of the same name defined in the prototype. Binding operations within the constructor always take precedence over those in the prototype.

When a constructor is invoked, the following happens:

- A new empty object is created.
- This object is passed to the constructor as the `this` parameter, and thus becomes the constructor's function context.
- In the absence of any explicit return value, the new object is returned as the constructor's value.

Other 3 JavaScript function invocations:

> - As a function

This type of invocation occurs when a function is invoked using the `()` operator, and the function context is the global context - usually the window object. For instance:

```js
function example(){ return this; };
alert(example() == window); // invocation as a function (`this` is the global context)
```

> - As a method

Happens when a function is assigned to a property of an object **and** the invocation occurs by referencing the function using that property. That object becomes the function context and is available within the function via the `this` parameter. This is one of the primary means by which JavaScript allows object-oriented code to be written. For instance:

```js
var example = {};
example.whatever = function(){ return this; };
alert(example == example.whatever()); // invocation as a method (`this` is the object to which this method belongs)
```

> - Via its apply() or call() methods

```js
var context = {};
function example() {
    alert(this == context); // showing that we set the context
}

example.call(context);      // invocation using `call`
```

The only difference is that `call()` takes the function arguments as comma separated, and `apply()` takes the function arguments in an array.

Answer (score 2):

**Method Invocation** - A method JavaScript function stored in a property of an object. In method invocation the object becomes the invocation context, and the function body can refer to that object using the keyword `this`.

```
var myContact = {

first: "greg",
last: "gum",
fullName: function()
   {
    return this.first + " " + this.last;
   }
}
```

**Constructor Invocation** - If a function or a method invocation is preceded by the keyword `new`, then it is a constructor invocation.

```
var myContact2 = function () {

this.first = "greg";
this.last = "gum";
this.fullName = function()
  {
    return this.first + " " + this.last;
  }
 };
```

If a constructor has no parameter, then argument list and paranthesis can be omitted. So these two are equivalent:

```
var aContact = new myContact2();
var aContact = new myContact2;
```

Answer (score 0):

myContact is a single instance.

myContact2 you can create multiple instances.

You left out

```
var myContact3 = function(){

    return {
        first: "greg",
        last: "gum",
        fullName: function()
        {
            return this.first + " " + this.last;
        }
    };

};
```

:)

Which is the best of both worlds until you want a prototype function!

Comment: OK, so I tried your example, and yes it works fine.  But what do you mean by it works until you want a prototype function?

Comment: in your example myContact2 each instance created with `new` will have a separate (duplicated) copy of the function. In c# all classes of the same type will have a single copy of a function and reference the instance data with `this`. To achieve the same efficiency in javascript you need to use prototype functions-

`myContact2.prototype.fullname = function(){ return this.first + " " + this.last;}` . But you will need to do more reading than this :)